# It' possible create a clause that mixes the clauses that it contains?

Tags: prolog

i have to get a value by developing a list through various clauses, but do not know the best combination between the clauses, because each clause removes items from the initial list and the subsequent works on the remaining list.

Is it possible to create a single clause that you find the best combination of the clauses?

```
calculate(List,Value):-
    calculate_value1(List,R,Value1),
    calculate_value1(List,R,Value2),
    calculate_value1(List,R,Value3),
    max([Value1,Valu2,Value3],Value).


calculate_value1(List,Rest,Value1):-
    funcA(List,Rest1,ValueA),
    funcB(Rest1,Rest2,ValueB),
    funcC(Rest2,Rest3,ValueC).
    Value1 is ValueA + ValueB + ValueC.

calculate_value2(List,Rest,Value2):-
    funcB(List,Rest1,ValueB),
    funcA(Rest1,Rest2,ValueA),
    funcC(Rest2,Rest3,ValueC).
    Value2 is ValueA + ValueB + ValueC.

calculate_value3(List,Rest,Value3):-
    funcC(List,Rest1,ValueC),
    funcB(Rest1,Rest2,ValueB),
    funcA(Rest2,Rest3,ValueA).
    Value3 is ValueA + ValueB + ValueC.
```

thank you.

I have to compare two lists and I have to be able to find the best balance between them. Then run on lists various clauses that identify if there are identical elements between the first and the second , and then with a ratio of 100 % or if one of a list is the sum of the other second . Also check if they are neighbors who have close relationship , 110 is closer to 100 than to 150 . But the data is not only numeric only .

Now I have several separate clauses : equals ( ) , that identifies the elements equally between the two lists , sum (), which identifies items with a ratio of the sum of them, multiply (), etc. ....
For each clause in the input do I get a list and a list of items that met the criteria of that clause (sum , multiplication, c ....) , with the percentage found and a list of remaining elements that give input to the clause next .

In doing so , however, is a procedural program , because I first calculate the elements the same, then the sum , etc ...

I would like to be able to create a dynamic program that is able to identify the best percentage in any order by clauses .

I hope I was more clear .

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible and it looks like there are typos in your code.

Comment: the code is only an example. I don't have tried to run it

Comment: Well maybe you should try to run it. How can I guess what you are trying to do if your question is incomprehensible and your code wrong?